# Cant deploy with Netlify and Stapi and Graphql

Tags: graphql, nuxt.js, backend, netlify, strapi

I am creating a website with Nuxt, graphql and strapi.
Locally with works well. I then deploy the backend in heuroku with mlab addon and also all good.
Went to netlify with the heuroku link and deploy it there( follow a tutorial). It said deployed successful  but when I open the page it says page not found. I went to see the deploy log and there is an error:

```
Error: Network error: request to http://localhost:1337/graphql failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:1337
10:16:00 AM:     at new ApolloError (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/apollo-client/bundle.umd.js:92:26)
10:16:00 AM:     at /opt/build/repo/node_modules/apollo-client/bundle.umd.js:1588:34
10:16:00 AM:     at /opt/build/repo/node_modules/apollo-client/bundle.umd.js:2008:15
10:16:00 AM:     at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
10:16:00 AM:     at /opt/build/repo/node_modules/apollo-client/bundle.umd.js:2006:26
10:16:00 AM:     at Map.forEach (<anonymous>)
10:16:00 AM:     at QueryManager.broadcastQueries (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/apollo-client/bundle.umd.js:2004:20)
10:16:00 AM:     at /opt/build/repo/node_modules/apollo-client/bundle.umd.js:1483:29
10:16:00 AM:     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

Any idea how to fix this? I search but couldn't find any answer that helped me.
Thank you

Comment: change the graphql URL to heroku subdomain.

Comment: How I do that? you mean with the heroku domains add:?

Answer (score 0):

It should be referencing the Heroku url. You need to change your database.js for Heroku. https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/deployment/heroku.html